# Where's the documentation on building a CocoaLibSpotify CLI app?

Tags: documentation, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I can swear I've seen documentation on how to build a command line application utilizing CocoaLibSpotify, but now I cannot find it. It's not in the CocoaLibSpotify Github repo's documentation. Where is it?

Edit: There's some info on how to use **libspotify** in command line applications under the section *4.2 Building command line applications* at https://github.com/reddavis/Le-Code/tree/master/Cocoa%20Spotify/Mac%20Framework/libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal
Does this also apply to the CocoaLibSpotify framework? Are there CocoaLibSpotify-specific instructions anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific CocoaLibSpotify documentation for this. However, it's not too bad — either compile CocoaLibSpotify as a static library and link it in or import all the files in the `common` folder directly into your app and compile them in directly.

When writing your app, since CocoaLibSpotify maintains its own background thread, you'll need to set up a runloop to your CLI doesn't terminate until you want it to. However, that's not specific to CocoaLibSpotify and a very common task for CLI apps.